# icCube - cumulative total in a chart

Tags: iccube-reporting

I have an icCube serial chart that displays a measure for a list of items, ordered from large to small.

I would like to use to display the cumulative total without using MDX, but using the function expression builder. Unfortunately I can not get it to work I I probably do something wrong in the syntax.

Does someone know how to make a javascript construction to get the cumulative value.

For example. the MDX result gives:

- item1  10
- item2  6
- item3  2

I would like the widget to present the data as:

- item1  10
- item2  16  ( 10 + 6 )
- item3  18  ( 10 + 6 + 2 )

And - please - pure javascript on the value definition in the graph using functions from the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Data Render part, the widget, we've to define a javascript function as value field. We'll add the function to directly calculate cumulative , but for we can use :

```
var ri = context.rowIndex;  // current row Index
var cumVal = 0;
var isNotNull = false;    // we've to add an ic3Add that supports nulls/empty
for ( var row = 0 ; row <= ri; row++ ) {   // all former including this
  var cellVal = context.getValue(row);
  cumVal += cellVal || 0 ; // handle 'empty' 
  isNotNull = isNotNull || cellVal;
}
// the job is done
if (isNotNull) 
    return cumVal;
else
    return
```

[image]

### Update for icCube v 6.2 (4285)

icCube 6.2 introduced new cumulative functions:

```
cumulativeRow(row:CtxCoord, measure?:CtxCoord, property?:string):number
cumulativeCol(column:CtxCoord, measure?:CtxCoord, property?:string):number
cumulativeTable(row:CtxCoord, column:CtxCoord, measure?:CtxCoord, property?:string):number
```

With this new functions new value for a **Value** property should be:

```
return context.cumulativeRow();
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.